# Переполнение целочислительной константы

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Почему происходит переполнение.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::size_t max = 1000000 * 1000 * 4;
}
```

> Предупреждение    C4307   *: переполнение целой константы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что, целочислительные литералы в коде имеют знаковый тип.

Comment: Что значит "почему"? Потому что значение не помещается в тип `int`. А это и есть переполнение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Константы (содержащие число) по умолчанию интерпретируются как 32-бит signed integer (вашему значению не хватает одного бита 31-бит+1 бит знаковый), но ваш тип 32-битный unsigned (size_t), поэтому нужно указать "суффикс" - тип литерала, в данном случае `U`. Числовые константы называют литералами (целые литералы или integer literals).

```
std::size_t max = 1000000U * 1000* 4;
```

Тип "литерала" определяется по-первому литералу, остальные участвующие в операции - компилятор конвертирует по-типу первого, поэтому следующие два U можно не указывать.

Целые литералы коротко: `U` - unsigned, `L`-long (32-битный), `UL` = unsigned 32-битный, `LL`-64-битный signed (C++11 стандарт), `ULL` -64-битный unsigned (тоже). (Длинна `U` совпадает с длинной `unsigned int`, которое в некоторых компиляторах может иметь длинну отличную от 32.)

Более подробно https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Если компилятор ругается на  1000000LL - значит ваш компилятор не поддерживает данный тип литерала - прийдется писать число полность. Если всё же надо "слиять код" - можете воспользоваться `#define` (обычно стараются избегать таких конструкций, но в данном случае считаю что можно применить). Например так

```
#define triple_const(a,b,c) a##b##c
std::size_t max = triple_const(4,000000,000)
```

Так же бывают другие типы литералов (строковые, булевые, числа с плавающей запятой и т п).

Answer (score 2):

`1000000 * 1000 * 4 == 4 000 000 000`, но это если `unsigned int`. В данном случае `int(1000000) * int(1000) * int(4)` — а это переполнение `int` и оно равно `-294967296`. Дальше отрицательное число присваивается типу `unsigned` — получается ерунда

Comment: не согласен. Механизм констант устроен по-другому. Наберите в дебагере Ctrl+Alt+W и вбейте `(unsigned)-294967296` - ну как вам результат? Не получается ерунда.

Comment: @nick_n_a, только вы не учли что у автора x64 битная среда, поэтому присвоение max эквивалентно (uint64_t)-294967296, а не (unsigned)

Comment: Нет, я вам пишу, надо было написать `(uint32_t)-294967296` будет как раз   4 000 000 000 - наверно вас удивит - это как раз в 32 бита. Для констант есть суффикс.

Comment: @nick_n_a, я вас не понию, я расписал как интерпретируется код автора, при чем тут `(unsigned)-294967296`? Я такого не писал.

Comment: Присвоение отрицательного числа unsigned типу тут ни при чем, компилятор ругается на сам факт переполнения.

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь вычислить значение выражения `1000000 * 1000 * 4`. Все операнды этого выражения имеют тип `int` и все выражение вычисляется в рамках домена типа `int`. Но это выражение на вашей платформе не может быть вычислено в рамках домена типа `int` - происходит переполнение. Об этом вам и говорит компилятор.